# How to get table columns with datatypes (and lengths) using PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

I'm trying to get column names with data types (and lengths) for SQL Server instance using PowerShell. I got this far:

```
#Load PSSnapin
Add-PSSnapin *SQL*

#Get column names
$colNames = dir 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYCOMPUTER\MYSQLINSTANCE\Databases\MYDATABASE\Tables' | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "dbo.MYTABLE"} | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.Columns} |
            Select-Object Name, DataType
$colNames
```

How to get also datatype lengths for columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lengths are found at `<Column>.Properties['Length'].Value`, so you can select it like:

```
#Get column names
$colNames = dir 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYCOMPUTER\MYSQLINSTANCE\Databases\MYDATABASE\Tables' | 
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "dbo.MYTABLE"} | 
        ForEach-Object {$_.Columns} |
            Select-Object Name, DataType, `
                @{Name='Length'; Expression = {$_.Properties['Length'].Value}}
$colNames
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I don't know the PowerShell syntax, but, heres the SQL for what you want:

```
SELECT 
    TableName = OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID), 
    ColumnName = c.name,
    DataType = t.name, -- Type is an int in the columns table, this returns the type name.
    MaxLength = c.max_length -- Returns the max length of the column.
FROM 
    sys.columns AS c
JOIN 
    sys.types AS t 
ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) = 'MYTABLE'
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to DirtyPaws.
SQL Statement with Powershell Syntax:

```
#Credentials
$SQLServer = "SQL ServerName/IP Address"
$SQLDBName = "DatabaseName"
$uid ="MySqlUser"
$pwd = "MySqlUserPassword"

#Establish SQL Connection
$connectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"

$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

#Create SQL Statement
$query = "
SELECT 
    TableName = OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID), 
    ColumnName = c.name,
    DataType = t.name, -- Type is an int in the columns table, this returns the type name.
    MaxLength = c.max_length -- Returns the max length of the column.
FROM 
    sys.columns AS c
JOIN 
    sys.types AS t 
ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE 
    OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) = 'MyTableName'
"

#Add SQL Query to SQL Connection
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

#Execute SQL Query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()

#Add result to DataTable Object and Display it
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)

Write-Host ($table | Format-Table | Out-String)
Write-Host ($table | Format-List | Out-String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different but very similar problem.
I needed to find the data type and length for a known single column.
The PowerShell needed to be robust enough to handle the precision and scale of decimal places.  With a little bit of tweaking the PowerShell below could be modified to apply to the original question as well:

```
$ColumnName = 'Your Column Name';

dir 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\MYCOMPUTER\MYSQLINSTANCE\Databases\MYDATABASE\Tables\dbo.TableName' | Select `
Name, `
DataType, `
@{Name='Length'; Expression = {$_.DataType.MaximumLength}},
@{Name='NumericPrecision'; Expression = {$_.DataType.NumericPrecision}}, `
@{Name='NumericScale'; Expression = {$_.DataType.NumericScale}} | ? Name -eq $ColumnName;
```